# Mirroring with xrandr with correct aspect ratio

Tags: xrandr

I have two screens with different resolutions: 1920x1080 (16:9) and 1680x1050 (16:10).
I would like to setup mirroring, so I scaled it like this:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary --mode 1680x1050
xrandr --output eDP1 --same-as HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale-from 1680x1050
```

Is it possible to change the command, so on eDP1 the image would keep correct aspect ratio, e.g. it would be 1728x1080 (16:10)  with black rectangles on the sides to fill 1920x1080?